# Visual Studio 2015 Xamarin tools

Tags: visual-studio, networking, xamarin.forms

I created a solution in Visual Studio 2015 using the Xamarin project type.  During the initial creation, it did something to my network settings.  I figured it was just doing what it needed to do to pretend to be an android phone or something.  However, now every time I reboot my computer I have to go to my network settings and repair the connection or I can't use the internet.

Google search has so far been less than productive.

Does anyone know what I can do to permanently repair this issue?

Comment: What emulator are you using ?

Comment: whatever one comes out of the box with Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Strange , this happened with me when I installed emulators which are based on VirtualBox

Comment: What was the solution for that?

Comment: Well basically , at that time , the emulators created based on Virtual boxes (Android Player) or ( Genimotion) . they create virtual network adapter that you can see when you check the Device manager on your windows . And that somehow can confuse your operating system. So I used to clean up and delete them. But I am not sure that it would solve your problem

Comment: I only see the one network adapter and my VPN connections, so i guess maybe I can try to delete and recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this required resetting my whole ethernet setup.  I used this guide:  [Digital Citizen network reset guide](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-reset-all-your-windows-10-network-adapters-just-6-clicks). The gist of it is this:

Open the Settings App in Windows 10

Enter the "Network and Internet Settings" category

Select the "Status tab from the left-hand side.

Select the "Network reset" command from the page that's displayed.

You will be prompted to restart your computer.  Click yes to all the options and make sure  your work is saved.  Restart your computer if it doesn't do so automatically.

I do not know if Visual Studio will mess this up again.

Comment: Answer:  Yes, yes it did.  the Xamarin forums were not super helpful about this issue.  Maybe I'll try Microsoft.